# C++ Encode string to string literals programmatically

Tags: c++, string, persistence, libpqxx

I'm trying to persist text that is input from some user into a db, how would I encode these values?  I'm a n00b in C/C++ and am having trouble with my google fu skills..

I'm using libpqxx and trying to do something like

```
std::string sql = "insert into chat values (nextval('chat_seq'), '" + userInput + "');";
work.exec(sql);
```

but when userInput is something like

```
I'm doing just fine
```

My insertion will fail. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Trying to create sql queries like this is exactly what leads to users being able to perform sql injection attacks. I recommend you read about sql injection, and then look up how to use parameterized queries, rather than just trying to encode your raw input. (This isn't an answer because I don't know anything about libpqxx, but I just googled and it looks like that library calls it "prepared statements" rather than parameterized.)

Comment: See also obligatory xkcd on the subject: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Yes this is what I should have done first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, look up SQL injection, there is a ton of resource on it.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet
http://www.veracode.com/security/sql-injection

A good start would be to identify the characters that cause injection and escape them or remove/replace the characters.

make sure userInput is a string and you have access to all the useful std string bits to do string maniupulation such as substr, replacement etc.

see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: OK I implement prepared statements, definitely much safer.. Now trying to expand on that I have posted another question about postgis prepared statements. Thank you both for the links.